# Using google oauth2 with php mailer

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, phpmailer

When I request a token i get a GET response of

```
> Showing GET Array (
>     [state] => 1025628ef33hdjs29342fafbd6605560
>     [code] => 4/yQE9qQ4S99UeKzjwz5W0slCx34d9ff4kxfYEhESLo80XDKH04SStj3xW4b0UrUSLryaUC2o3tbPtajeYgkQR4g
>     [scope] => email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
>     [authuser] => 0
>     [hd] => mywebsite.net
>     [prompt] => none )
```

My question is what is the parameter [code]
I am using this for phpmailer and is the parameter [code] the refreshtoken?

```
//Create a new OAuth2 provider instance
$provider = new Google(
    [
        'clientId' => $clientId,
        'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
    ]
);

//Pass the OAuth provider instance to PHPMailer
$mail->setOAuth(
    new OAuth(
        [
            'provider' => $provider,
            'clientId' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
            'userName' => $email,
        ]
    )
);
```

As I am only getting the following response when I send mail and no mail is being recieved

```
2020-04-04 14:06:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP k18sm8991709qkh.46 - gsmtp
2020-04-04 14:06:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO simplifiedchurch.net
2020-04-04 14:06:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [100.8.194.132]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2020-04-04 14:06:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-04-04 14:06:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2020-04-04 14:06:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO simplifiedchurch.net
2020-04-04 14:06:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [100.8.194.132]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer is I was getting a grant error. The grant error was caused by the requirement to enable the gmail app to run phpmailer, which I did not notice at first.